# Same layout but moved a bit to the right

Tags: android

I have 2 different layouts.

```xml
<ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.CopyBarVisualizer xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bar_top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    custom:avColor="#D11817"
    custom:avDensity="0.0"
    custom:avGravity="bottom"
    custom:avSpeed="fast"
    custom:avWidth="20dp" />

<ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.CopyBarVisualizer xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:rotation="180"
    app:avColor="#D11817"
    app:avDensity="0.0"
    app:avGravity="bottom"
    app:avSpeed="fast"
    app:avWidth="20dp"
   />
```

The second one has a rotation of 180 and has been placed below the first one.

My problem is that the one below, looks like it has been moved a little bit to the right and I have no idea why. This is how it looks like:

[image]

As you see, they are not on the same lines.

I have tried to fix the second one with

```xml
android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
```

but that is not doing anything (probably because I am using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`).

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix that issue by adding `RelativeLayout` to each of these layouts. So `RelativeLayout` will be centered and so I can use the attribute `android:layout_marginRight` for the second layout to move it more to the left.

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.CopyBarVisualizer xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bar_top"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        custom:avColor="#D11817"
        custom:avDensity="0.0"
        custom:avGravity="bottom"
        custom:avSpeed="fast"
        custom:avWidth="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <ch.yourclick.kitt.classes.CopyBarVisualizer xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:avColor="#D11817"
        app:avDensity="0.0"
        app:avGravity="bottom"
        app:avSpeed="fast"
        app:avWidth="20dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```